# Can I receive mobile push notifications from SNS without a dedicated app?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I want to setup some maintenance related messages that would be dispatched to Slack and ideally some mobile users via push notifications (avoiding SMS if I can). I already handled Slack via some SNS + Lambda combo, and I'm tackling the Mobile push part.

I was somehow hoping I could just subscribe my phone number to some SNS channel but I guess its not so simple yet...

If my understanding is correct, it is not possible to receive push notifications without an App, since the Cloud-to-mobile-push service actually needs a client running on the device. 
Actually, from what I can read on the internet it would seem most articles and documentations explain how to setup push notifications inside some application along with other features (and basically the push notifications is just one feature amongst the others), and that the push notification is not an end in itself.

However, I am just interested subscribing to push notifications as an end in itself (I don't need any other app feature).

What is the way to proceed in this case ? Are there some generic apps that are made for this and would let me subscribe to any mobile "push-list" ? Are there some kits that let one easily make an app just for the purpose of receiving push messages ? Is there maybe a builtin way in Android/iOS to subscribe to a push list without downloading a different app ?

EDIT : I am in the eu-central-1 region. I have some serviced in eu-west-1   (sending emails to SES) but otherwise all my servers and alarms are in eu-central-1

Comment: Might not be exactly what you're looking for, but SNS also supports delivery of messages via SMS.

Comment: @Dunedan unfortunately it seems like it is not supported in my region (eu-central-1)

Comment: SNS can send SMSes to countries around eu-central-1 (e.g. France), see https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/ for supported networks...

Comment: You need a native app running in the device since the push message is addressed to a token that is unique to your app on a given device. Without an app to request a token you cannot address the push.

Comment: Are you sure it has to be a native app @Paulw11 ? Then what about Progressive Web Applications that claim they can receive push notifications ?

Comment: I should qualify; I am referring to iOS. It may be different in Android.